# HEAD is now at 253c43d25 Merge pull request #13060 from Random

Tags: homebrew

```
Press RETURN/ENTER to continue or any other key to abort:
/usr/bin/sudo/usr/sbin/chown
-R ahmedkahie: admin /opt/homebrew
==>
Downloading and installing Homebrew..
HEAD is now at 253c43d25 Merge pull request #13060 from RandomDSdevel/revert-130
44-taps-rubocop-config
error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
fatal: ambiguous argument
'refs/remotes/origin/master': unknown revision or path
not in the working tree
Use
to separate paths from revisions, like this:'git <command> [‹revision>[‹file>.. ]
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the installation is stuck but you just need to wait until you get this message:

```
fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
==> Installation successful!
```

Ignore the error as the installation should still be successful.

Comment: Worked for me. Just took a couple minutes for installation to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, it's might can be a connection issue. Try to do:

`sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew`

before installation.
It must helps you.